# Positioning or animating a view programmatically during launch phase

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout, android-animation, android-viewbinding

I have a `Fragment` and `viewBinding` is available. I want to re-position a `View` in my `ConstraintLayout`.

Let's say I have three views (RedView, GreenView and BlueView), RedView and GreenView are fixed in their position and BlueView should position itself on top of one of these fixed-positioned views when I **want**.

Scenario: position BlueView on RedView when I launch the app.

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        binding.blue.alpha = 1f // this changes alpha value
        binding.blue.x = binding.red.x // this won't change x position
        binding.blue.y = 200f // this will change y position
    }
```

getting `x` and `y` values of a view with viewBinding on `onViewCreated` doesn't return anything.

However if I animate it via an `Event`, it works.

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
         ...
         binding.redView.setOnClickListener{ view ->
             animateBlueView(view).start() // x and y position will be changed
        }
    }

fun animateBlueView(view: View): AnimatorSet {
        val x = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(binding.blue.x, view.x).apply {
            duration = 300
            addUpdateListener {
                binding.blue.x = animatedValue as Float
            }
        }

        val y = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(binding.blue.y, view.y).apply {
            duration = 300
            addUpdateListener {
                binding.blue.y = animatedValue as Float
            }
        }

        return AnimatorSet().apply {
            play(x).with(y)
        }
}
```

When I try to trigger the animation in `onViewCreated` programmatically, animation doesn't start.

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        ...
        animateBlueView(binding.red).start()
    }
```

I am missing something fundamental but I don't know what it is. Can someone explain what's going on and what should I look for?

Answer (score 0):

```
fun animateBlueView(view: View): AnimatorSet {

    val x = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(binding.blue.x, view.x).apply {
        duration = 300
        addUpdateListener {
            binding.blue.x = animatedValue as Float
        }
    }


    val y = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(binding.blue.y, view.y).apply {
        duration = 300
        addUpdateListener {
            binding.blue.y = animatedValue as Float
        }
    }


    return AnimatorSet().apply {
        play(x).with(y)
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).